# Unit Test NgRx effect with fromEvent stream

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

How do you unit test an NgRx Effect that listens to a window event?

I know how the Unit Test is setup with the actions stream as this is well documented, but I could not find an example to test this with event listeners.

Here is the effect I would like to unit test:

```
openKeyboard$ = createEffect(() => {
  return fromEvent(window, 'ionKeyboardDidShow').pipe(mapTo(KeyboardActions.keyboardOpened()));
});
```

The unit test description would look something like that:

```
describe('openKeyboard$', () => {
  it('dispatches keyboardOpened action on ionKeyboardDidShow window event', () => {
    // how to test this?
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of found a solution that works by just dispatching the window event but I am not really sure if this is an elegant one

```
describe('openKeyboard$', () => {
  it('dispatches keyboardOpened action on ionKeyboardDidShow window event', (done) => {
    effects.openKeyboard$.subscribe((res) => {
      expect(res).toEqual(KeyboardActions.keyboardOpened());
      done();
    });

    const eventMock = new Event('ionKeyboardDidShow');
    window.dispatchEvent(eventMock);
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems fine to me 